# Need to filter a large SAS data set on a list of 2000+ diagnosis codes. Should I use the IF statement or try to merge?

Tags: sas

I have a list of 2000+ dx codes for cancer. I have a large SAS data set for which there are 10 variables for dx codes, from dx1-dx10 (i.e., primary dx and then 9 secondary dx fields). What is the best way to filter the large SAS data set based on the 2000+ cancer codes? I first tried this:

```
%macro cancer;
    data cancer_set;
        set lib.big_set;
        array dx {*} dx1-dx10;
        do i=1 to 10;
            if dx[i] in ('1234' '2345' #etc. these are where I put the cancer codes#) then output;
        end;
    run;
%mend;
%cancer;
```

I actually haven't managed to get it to work because I was having problems with the LRECL option and also had errors about SAS unable to convert from character to numeric for some codes. A coworker suggested trying to merge, so I created a separate data set of the cancer codes. But- how do I merge when I have to look through each dx field of the big data set? I've also googled hash objects but can't seem to find an example where I can use the hash object as a lookup for more than one field. I need to be able to loop through all 10 dx codes. Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: My SAS is very rusty... but you could use a `PROC FORMAT` with a dataset of codes as your input that all translate to `1` or some value... then your loop becomes - `if format(dx[i], ccode.) == 1 then output;` or similar... Note... if more than one code matches, you'll be outputting more than once - is that correct?

Comment: This is basically a duplicate.  Put the dx's into a dataset, and then the linked question applies.  (Specifically, @JonClements is correct - a format is the simplest way to do this.)  You can do the array loop as you do above, and just use the `put` or `input` with the custom format inside that loop (`if put(dx[i],YOURFORMAT.) ='1' then output;`).  (Also, the macro wrapper here is pointless.)

Comment: Thank you! I will try that and follow up. Sorry for the duplicate question, but I appreciate the response and pointers. I see now that the macro is pointless.